# Statusline – update variables on file change

Tags: vimscript, autocmd, statusline, variables

I'm currently learning Vimscript, but I'm stuck at a particular problem.

I'm creating a statusline which shows the full path (~) of the file currently displayed in the buffer. Instead of just using %F, I'm creating two separate highlight groups to show the difference between the cwd and the active file. Example:

~/projects/projName/**subDir/file.md**

My current solution:

```
let file = fnamemodify(expand("%:p"), ":~")
let pwd = system('print -P %~')

hi pwd guifg=#FFFFFF
hi file guifg=#FFF093 gui=bold

set statusline=
set statusline+=%#pwd#[%{pwd}/
set statusline+=%#file#%{file[len(pwd):]}
```

This works …until you switch files, and nothing updates, which makes sense given the above code. I'm just not sure to continue from here. I've tried to wrap the variables inside autocommands for different buffer events, but that doesn't help. Neither does assigning `fnamemodify` or `system` directly to the statusline, as that gives an error when trying to source my vimrc

Thoughts?

**Update**

Ben Knoble has suggested a function returning a string, and that the statusline should simply call that function. This works with the exception of highlight groups now being outputted as just plain strings

```
hi pwd guifg=#BADA55
hi file guifg=#FFF093 gui=bold

function! SetStatusLine()
  return
    \ "%#pwd#" . system('print -P %~') .
    \ "%#file#" . fnamemodify(expand("%:p"), ":~")[len(system('print -P %~')):]
endfunction

set statusline=%{SetStatusLine()}
```

The statusline now updates as it should, but highlight groups don't work. My statsline currently shows the following:

%#pwd#~%#file#.vimrc

Close! Any other ideas?

**Update 2**

…Minor brainfart, you just use multiple functions for each highlight group. It works now!

Comment: Have you tried pulling the whole thing into a function and assigning statusline to evaluate that function?

Comment: I have not. Do you have a small, dumbed down example of such a function?

Comment: Hm, the 4 lines just above your assignment of statusline would be a good example actually (short and simple). Then you would *probably* return the string that comprises the statusline you want. This is how e.g. airline controls the statusline.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and I'm closer! The problem now is highlight groups not working, hmmm.. Updated original post with the new code.

Comment: Nevermind… You just use multiple functions for each highlight group..

Comment: You should self-answer with the solution that worked for you; that way others can benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it going thanks to some simple functions!

```
hi pwd guifg=#BADA55
hi file guifg=#FFF093 gui=bold
hi line guifg=#FFFFFF
hi statuslinenc gui=none
hi statusline gui=none

function! SetStatusLinePath()
     return system('print -P %~')[:-2] . "/"
endfunction

function! SetStatusLineFile()
     return fnamemodify(expand("%:p"), ":~")[len(system('print -P %~')):]
endfunction

set statusline=–––⎜
set statusline+=%#pwd#%{SetStatusLinePath()}
set statusline+=%#file#%{SetStatusLineFile()}
set statusline+=%#line#⎟
```

Here's a picture of my statusline as of now, just to visually show what I was trying to accomplish.

[image: Statusline-picture]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done much more simply with the `expand()` command:

```
function! SetStatusLinePath()
     return expand("%:h") . "/"
endfunction

function! SetStatusLineFile()
     return expand("%:t")
endfunction

set statusline+=%#pwd#%{SetStatusLinePath()}
set statusline+=%#file#%{SetStatusLineFile()}
```

see `:h expand()`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks!